# Cucumber-JAVA : Getting issue while starting and stopping the driver using ConcurrentEventListener

Tags: event-listener, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I am able to successfully initiate the driver when the feature file starts, and the driver stops once all the scenarios within that feature file have executed. However, there are two issues with the code I've written.

Issue 1: The driver behaves unexpectedly when tags are used in the feature file.

| Sample-Feature_File |
| --- |
| Feature: Sample_1 |
|  |
| @Run |
| Scenario: This is a sample scenario for feature 1_1 |
| Given This is a pre-condition statement |
| When This is an action statement |
| Then This is an assertion statement |
|  |
| Scenario: This is a sample scenario for feature 1_2 |
| Given This is a pre-condition statement |
| When This is an action statement |
| Then This is an assertion statement |
|  |
| Scenario: This is a sample scenario for feature 1_3 |
| Given This is a pre-condition statement |
| When This is an action statement |
| Then This is an assertion statement |

Issue 2: Scenario count mismatches. Let's say there are two feature files:

Feature 1 has 3 scenarios.
Feature 2 has 2 scenarios.

In this scenario, the driver initiates when the feature file begins. However, after the second scenario, the driver stops and then starts again. This occurs because Feature 2 has 2 scenarios. This should not to happen

When the third scenario of Feature 1 completes and Feature 2 begins, the driver once again stops and starts and It then stops after both scenarios in Feature 2 have been executed, and this behavior is correct.

```
/**
 * Handler for when a test case starts.
 * It initializes the driver and checks if it's the start of a new feature.
 */
private void handleTestCaseStarted(TestCaseStarted event) {
    if(DriverContext.getDriver() != null) {
        LOGGER.info("Driver Session ID at start of scenario: " + DriverContext.getDriver().getSessionId());
    } else {
        LOGGER.error("Driver is null at start of scenario.");
    }
    
    String newFeatureFile = event.getTestCase().getUri().toString();

    // Check for the start of a new feature and initialize driver if necessary
    if (isFirstFeature.get()) {
        LOGGER.info("NEW FEATURE STARTED: STARTING DRIVER");
        DriverFactory.getMobileDriverManager().startDriver();
        isFirstFeature.set(false);
    } else if (!currentFeatureFile.get().equals(newFeatureFile)) {
        LOGGER.info("NEW FEATURE STARTED: STARTING DRIVER");
        DriverFactory.getMobileDriverManager().startDriver();
    }

    // Update the current feature file and reset scenario count if it's a new feature
    if (!currentFeatureFile.get().equals(newFeatureFile)) {
        currentFeatureFile.set(newFeatureFile);
        executedScenariosCount.get().set(0);
    }
}

/**
 * Handler to read and store the current feature file details.
 */
private void readFeatureFile(TestSourceRead event) {
    currentFeatureFile.set(event.getUri().toString());
    totalScenariosInCurrentFeature.set(countScenariosInFeatureContent(event.getSource()));
}

/**
 * Handler for when a test case finishes.
 * It checks if all scenarios in the feature have been executed and stops the driver if necessary.
 */
private void handleTestCaseFinished(TestCaseFinished event) {
    if(DriverContext.getDriver() != null) {
        LOGGER.info("Driver Session ID at end of scenario: " + DriverContext.getDriver().getSessionId());
    } else {
        LOGGER.error("Driver is null at end of scenario.");
    }

    int count = executedScenariosCount.get().incrementAndGet();
    if (count == totalScenariosInCurrentFeature.get()) {
        LOGGER.info("FEATURE COMPLETED: STOPPING DRIVER");
        DriverFactory.getMobileDriverManager().quitDriver();
    }
}

/**
 * count the number of scenarios in the feature content.
 */
private int countScenariosInFeatureContent(String content) {
    int numberOfScenarios = 0;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(content);
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine().trim();
        for (ScenarioPattern pattern : ScenarioPattern.values()) {
            if (pattern.matches(line)) {
                numberOfScenarios++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    scanner.close();
    return numberOfScenarios;
}
```

}